# I want to save a pointer to a function in a Global variable

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

So i thought this would be straight forward but i keep getting compile errors, which probably means i am doing something stupid.

So i am using C and i want to save a pointer to a function in a global variable.

As a test case i have three files. Test.c, Test.h and FunctionPtr.c

Test.h goes like this

```
void (*MyCallBack)(void);

int SetFunc( void (*CallBackArg)(void));
void CallFunc();
```

Test.c Goes like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "test.h"
void SetFunc( void (*CallBackArg)(void)){

    printf("Set CallBack\n");
    MyCallBack=CallBackArg;
}

void CallFunc(){
    printf("In Call Func\n");
    MyCallBack();
}
```

and FunctionTest.c goes like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "test.h"


void MyFunc(){
    printf("Work!\n");
}
int main()
{
    SetFunc(MyFunc);
    CallFunc();

}
```

When i compile using  gcc FunctionTest.c  test.c test.h -o FunctionTest

I get the following error...

test.c:4: error: conflicting types for ‘SetFunc’
test.h:4: note: previous declaration of ‘SetFunc’ was here

I cant figure out what i am doing wrong? Perhaps i am not declaring the Global Pointer right?

Comment: Not that it matters much, but your `Callback` function itself has no prototype at all. In contrast to C++, declaring a function without its arguments says that it may receive an unspecified number of arguments. Give it a `void` in there such that then all your three prototypes agree. Best practice for the function pointer arguments would be to declare a typedef and use that.

Comment: In _Test.h_ you have `void (*MyCallBack)(void);`, which is a variable declaration.  Every file that includes _Test.h_ might get its own copy of this variable.  You should have `extern void (*MyCallBack)(void);` in _Test.h_ and `void (*MyCallBack)(void);` in _Test.c_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int SetFunc( void (*CallBackArg)(void));

void SetFunc( void (*CallBackArg)(void))
```

The return types are different, that's your problem. You have to declare it the same way in the header as in the .c file.

Comment: Yeah your right, that is the reason for this test file to not work.

Comment: But then i looked at the actual code in my project and it turned out that the real problem was that i was doing a void (*MyCallBack)(void)=NULL; and that was causing the compiler to give those cryptic errors. 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Test.c has it returning void

```
void SetFunc( void (*CallBackArg)(void)){
```

Test.h has it returning int

```
 int SetFunc( void (*CallBackArg)(void));
```

Presumably you meant void, as it doesn't return anything